# Microphoning a Cajón in Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

It is needed to draw a Cajón with Microphoning as shown in the picture. The basic code is as follow:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{musixtex}

\newcommand{\microphone}{%
    \tikz{
        \begin{scope}
            \clip (-.3em,-.4ex) rectangle (1.3em,1.5ex);
            \fill[black, rounded corners=1.5ex] (-.3em,-.4ex) rectangle (1.3em,5.5ex);
        \end{scope}
        \fill[white, rounded corners=1.3ex] (-.1em,0) rectangle (1.1em,5.1ex);
        \fill[black, rounded corners=1.1ex] (0,.2ex) rectangle (1em,5ex);
        \foreach \pos in {2.5ex, 2.9ex, 3.3ex, 3.7ex}
            \fill[white, rounded corners=.1ex] (.35em,\pos) rectangle +(.8em,.25ex);
        \fill[black] (.4em,-.4ex) rectangle (.6em,-1.5ex);
        \fill[black] (0,-1.5ex) rectangle (1em,-2ex);
    }%
}


\begin{document}

{\Huge \microphone}


\end{document}
```

[image: current]
The desired output is as follow:

[image: desired]

Comment: Cajón is a percussion Peruvian instrument

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A little simplification, using `perspective` and `3d` Ti*k*Z libraries. The first one sets the view (a rotated isometric view in this case) and the second is helpful to draw in a plane parallel to xy, xz or yz planes with the options

```
canvas is xy plane at z=0
```

for example.

This is what I suggest:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{3d,perspective}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,
                    isometric view,rotate around z=185]
% Cajón
\draw[canvas is xy plane at z=0.05,rounded corners] (1,2) -| (2,1);
\draw[canvas is xz plane at y=0.05,rounded corners] (1,4) -| (2,1);
\draw[canvas is yz plane at x=0.05,rounded corners] (1,4) -| (2,1);
\draw[canvas is xy plane at z=4   ,rounded corners] (0.05,0.05) rectangle (1.95,1.95);
\draw[canvas is xz plane at y=2   ,rounded corners] (0.05,0.05) rectangle (1.95,3.95);
\draw[canvas is yz plane at x=2   ,rounded corners] (0.05,0.05) rectangle (1.95,3.95);
\draw[canvas is xz plane at y=2]                    (1,2.2) circle (0.4);
% Microphone
\begin{scope}[shift={(1,3.5,2.2)}]
\draw (0,0,0) circle (0.2cm); % sphere
\draw[canvas is xz plane at y=0] (-45:0.2) arc (-45:135:0.2); % equator
\draw[canvas is xz plane at y=0] (-45:0.2) arc (-45:135:0.2);
\pgfmathsetmacro\h{0.15}                % cylinder position
\pgfmathsetmacro\r{sqrt(0.2*0.2-\h*\h)} % cylinder radius
\foreach\i in {0,1}
{% some coordinates
   \begin{scope}[canvas is xz plane at y=\i+\h]
     \coordinate (A\i) at (-45:\r);
     \coordinate (B\i) at (135:\r);
   \end{scope}
}
% cylinder
\draw[canvas is xz plane at y=1+\h] (0,0) coordinate (P) circle (\r);
\draw[canvas is xz plane at y=\h,fill=white] (A0) arc (-45:135:\r) -- (B1) arc (135:-45:\r) -- cycle;
\draw[double] (P) to[out=-20,in=180] (0,2,-1); % wire
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]